# reload UITableView inside closure causes strange behaviour

Tags: swift, ios8, closures, cloudkit

I am using `CloudKit` to fetch `CKRecords` to populate a `UITableView`.
The `operations` Array acts as the datasource for the tableView

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Operation", predicate: predicate)
let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

operations = []
queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = {
        record in
        self.operations.append(record)
    }
queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = {
    cursor, error in
    if error == nil {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.tableView.reloadData()})
    }
}
let database = CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase
database.addOperation(queryOperation)
```

If i simply use `self.tableView.reload()` in the closure the tableView will update but there is a 5-10s delay unless I swipe the tableView where the cells will suddenly show. However when I dispatch on the main thread (as in the code above) the tableView cells will show but sometimes the top cell starts flashing or it renders very strange. I am wondering if anyone has any tips on how to implement the `tableView.reloadData()` inside this closure?

EDIT: This behaviour only seems to appear when i call the above code from `viewDidLoad`. If i call the above code after the tableview updates fine.

Comment: How about `dispatch_async` to the main queue?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately it did not solve it

Comment: Does this happen both on simulator and on device?

Comment: Good question, don't know how to test it on the simulator as it won't allow iCloud

Comment: you can run your app in the simulator with an iCloud account. Just start up your simulator go to the home screen (menu hardware, home) open the settings app, go to iCloud and log in. You do have to execute the reloadData on the main queue. Looking at your code. I don't think your problem has to do with iCloud.

Comment: Thanks for that. I ended up changing my approach to include CoreData as a local cache which also solved the rendering problems.